# New election or calling up candidates from a previous election

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Sometimes, I see that people from a previous election are called up to meet the additional demand. For example:

- In 2015 2 mods were called up additionally ([Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/7))
- Also in 2015, 2 additional mods were called up ([Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6))
- In 2011, 1 extra mod was called up ([Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2))
- And also in 2011, 2 additional mods were called up ([Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1))

When does the staff team decide to organize a new election, compared to calling up candidates from a previous election?

I thought that it may depend on the amount of available positions, but considering that in 2011 and 2015 2 mods were called up additionally, and right now there is [an election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9) going on for 2 positions, this doesn't seem to be true.

So, this made me wonder when an election is organized or when people from a previous election are chosen.

Comment: Generally a new election is held when it's been long enough after the last one, to give new candidates a chance. These additional mods were called up within a month after their respective elections to meet additional demand at short notice.

Comment: @BoltClock ah, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: SO is restoring from backups?

Comment: A year later, previous candidates may no longer be interested.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's not so much of a problem, because you could ask and they could just decline.  It's more concerning that a year later there will be new candidates are either qualified, or interested, and that may be better candidates than runner ups from the previous year.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When we decide it's time to bring in new moderators, we typically will check to see when the last election took place.  We try to avoid calling up more moderators when it has been a long time since the last election... long time meaning > 6 months.

We do that because new qualified people might be interested in nominating themselves, and/or those who were runners-up to the previous election may no longer want to be a mod.

Once we've checked the time since the previous election, we decide if we should call-up people or run a new election.